# как активировать аккаунт на время при регистрации? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

создал в таблице поле status как правильно сделать чтобы когда пользователь регистрируется, status имел значение active к примеру на 1 месяц потом если в течении месяца его не продлить то он становится noactive, а если продлить то установить определенное время к примеру на месяц или 3 месяца и т.д.

Comment: Храните дату последней активности пользователя, при регистрации заполняйте текущей датой и при каждом входе на сайт обновляйте. По крону проверяйте это поле и при необходимости делайте что вы там хотите с неактивными аккаунтами

Comment: мне нужно установить на время задать активацию к примеру на месяц

Answer (score 0):

Думаю стоит использовать тип колонки dateTimе и указывать время до которого есть доступ. Проверять больше ли оно текущего времени если да - подписка действует.
При регистрации устанавливать 1 месяц и потом уже добавить возможность на продление на нужный срок.